# "Satisfied with" vs. "satisfied by" vs. "satisfied in"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, collocation, past-participles

> He was satisfied with his test result.
>   He was satisfied by his test result.
>   He ws satisfied in his test result.

Is there any difference between these?

Answer (score 6):

"He was satisfied *with* his test results" means that he was happy with them. The test results meet his expectations ([dictionary.com, definition 1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satisfy)).

"He was satisfied *by* his test results" is similar, but has the idea that the first *he* had some need or other metaphorical container filled by the test results of the second *he* (the two references to *he* may refer to the same person or to different people). For example, a teacher (the first *he*) who had spent a lot of personal time with a student (the second *he*) might consider the favour repaid (i.e. *satisfied by*) the student's good results. Depending on context, it could also have other shades of meaning - see the [dictionary.com entries after #1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satisfy).

"Satisfied in" is not a grammatical construction.

Here's another example. If Sam is fed some food that fills him up but which isn't really very good quality, you might say that Sam (or more precisely, Sam's hunger) is satisfied *by* the food, and that Sam is not satisfied *with* the food.

Comment: Good example, *satisfied by the food/satisfied with the food*.

Comment: 'Satisfied' is here a perfect participle in a passive voice clause, so 'by' points out the agent; which is a stronger association than 'with'.

Answer (score 4):

> He was satisfied with his test result.

This one is idiomatic, meaning the person was pleased or happy with the result. *Satisfied* is an adjective here, and it collocates with the preposition "with":

> **satisfied** *(adjective)*: pleased with what has happened or with what you have achieved
>   **satisfied with**: *The President declared himself satisfied with the progress of the talks.*

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/satisfied))

> He was satisfied by his test result.

It's not ungrammatical, but it sounds a bit awkward. *Satisfied* is a verb (passive voice) here, and the sentence is grammatically equivalent to *The test result satisfied him* (active voice).

> He was satisfied in his test result.

This does not sound idiomatic or grammatical to me.